# How to redirect URL and remove the query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I have this URL:

> https://www.example.co.uk/about-us.html?7ec4b46ae6eaa4c756b968f5d2ef3c91=393a66ccb81d9b440d6b104f793224a8

and I would like to redirect it to:

> https://www.example.co.uk/about-us/

The best result I can get so far is just being able to redirect to /about-us/ but it also appends the query string to the end. How can I redirect this URL and remove the query string?

So far I have tried:

```
Redirect 301 /about-us.html?7ec4b46ae6eaa4c756b968f5d2ef3c91=393a66ccb81d9b440d6b104f793224a8 https://www.example.co.uk/about-us/
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/about-us.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ about-us? [R=301,L]
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try  :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /about-us\.html\?7ec4b46ae6eaa4c756b968f5d2ef3c91=393a66ccb81d9b440d6b104f793224a8 [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://exmaple.com/about-us? [L,R]
```

The `?` at end of the Rule's destination is important as it discards the old query string from the new url otherwise if you remove the question mark your new url will look something like :

```
https://www.example.co.uk/about-us?7ec4b46ae6eaa4c756b968f5d2ef3c91=393a66ccb81d9b440d6b104f793224a8
```

Clear your browser  cache before testing this Rule.

Comment: Thanks for this but unfortunately this did not resolve the issue. The page did not redirect at all with this. Also tried in other browsers to make sure it was not a browser caching issue.

Comment: @Graham What happens when you type the url into your browser?  What error do you get?

Comment: no error, the URL just did not redirect and went to the old page instead. (which is a 404)

Comment: Are you sure `mod-rewrite` is enabled on your server?

Comment: I did phpinfo() to check and could not see any signs that it was enabled, however the site is a Wordpress site which is running completely fine. Not sure if that helps? Is there a way around this issue if mod-rewrite is not enabled?